# Applying Styles To ListItems in CheckBoxList

Tags: asp.net, html, controls, coding-style

How can styles be applied to CheckBoxList ListItems.  Unlike other controls, such as the Repeater where you can specify `<ItemStyle>`, you can't seem to specify a style for each individual control.

Is there some sort of work around?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can add Attributes to ListItems programmatically as follows.

Say you've got a CheckBoxList and you are adding ListItems.  You can add Attributes along the way.

```
ListItem li = new ListItem("Richard Byrd", "11");
li.Selected = false;
li.Attributes.Add("Style", "color: red;");
CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(li);
```

This will make the color of the listitem text red.  Experiment and have fun.

Answer (score 14):

It seems the best way to do this is to create a new CssClass.  ASP.NET translates CheckBoxList into a table structure.

Using something like

Style.css

```
.chkboxlist td 
{
    font-size:x-large;
}
```

Page.aspx

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkboxlist1" runat="server" CssClass="chkboxlist" />
```

will do the trick

Comment: This of course affects all the listitems, to affect a single listitem you need to add attributes to the listitem as it is created.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I was going more for something like how a repeater can apply a style to each item, but this is certainly helpful :)

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Andrew's answer...

Depending on what other attributes you put on a `CheckBoxList` or `RadioButtonList`, or whatever, ASP.Net will render the output using different structures. For example, if you set `RepeatLayout="Flow"`, it won't render as a TABLE, so you have to be careful of what descendant selectors you use in your CSS file.

In *most* cases, you can can just do a "View Source" on your rendered page, maybe on a couple of different browsers, and figure out what ASP.Net is doing. There is a danger, though, that new versions of the server controls or different browsers will render them differently.

If you want to style a particular list item or set of list items differently without adding in attributes in the code-behind, you can use CSS attribute selectors. The only drawback to that is that they aren't supported in IE6. [jQuery](http://jquery.com) fully supports CSS 3 style attribute selectors, so you could probably also use it for wider browser support.

Comment: An example of CSS styling using  CSS attribute selectors would have been enlightening in this case.

Answer (score 5):

You can also achieve this in the markup.

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Good" Value="True" style="background-color:green;color:white" />
<br />
<asp:ListItem Text="Bad" Value="False" style="background-color:red;color:white" />
```

The word Style will be underlined with the warning that *Attribute 'style' is not a valid attribute of element 'ListItem'.*, but the items are formatted as desired anyway.

Comment: + 1. That's cool, too. Although I would worry at a later time that they make it so this workaround doesn't work any longer.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist As long as ASP.NET controls turn into HTML elements in the browser, the style workaround will work. In other words, I don't see it ever breaking.

Answer (score 2):

You can even have different font styles and color for each word.

```
<asp:ListItem Text="Other (<span style=font-weight:bold;>please </span><span>style=color:Red;font-weight:bold;>specify</span>):" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool Repeater_Bind()
{
    RadioButtonList objRadioButton = (RadioButtonList)eventArgs.Item.FindControl("rbList");
    if (curQuestionInfo.CorrectAnswer != -1) {
        objRadioButton.Items[curQuestionInfo.CorrectAnswer].Attributes.Add("Style", "color: #b4fbb1;");
    }
}
```

Comment: this adds an attribute to a span that wraps the actual input, so be aware.