# Is there a possibility to assign CssClass to CheckBox within CheckBoxList

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, .net-3.5

I need to assign display style (CssClass) to every CheckBox within CheckBoxList. I would like to do it separately for every CheckBox.
And the last requirement is that I have to do it on server side within my .net code.

Comment: When you say you want to do it separately for every CheckBox, does that mean you may want some CheckBoxes in the list with styling and some without?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104458/applying-styles-to-listitems-in-checkboxlist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not explicitly.  You can use Attributes:

```
ListItem myItem = CheckBoxList1.Items[itemIndex];
myItem.Attributes["bgcolor"] = "lightblue";
```

As far as having each checkbox use CssClass, each CheckBox is actually a [ListItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) and that class does not support CssClass.