# Add CssClass to asp:ListItem within CheckBoxList

Tags: css, asp.net, checkboxlist

I want to add a Css-Class to a `<asp:ListItem>` within a `<asp:CheckBoxList>`.

This is my code:

```
<fieldset class="group">
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="checkboxID" runat="server" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" RepeatColumns="1" CssClass="choose" RepeatDirection="Vertical" RepeatLayout="UnorderedList" TextAlign="Right" EnableViewState="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Checkbox 1" Value="checkbox_10" />
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
</fieldset>
```

This is what I get:

```
<fieldset class="group">
    <ul id="checkboxID2" class="choose">
        <li>
            <input id="checkboxID_0" type="checkbox" name="checkboxID$0" value="checkbox_10" />
            <label for="checkboxID_0">Checkbox 1</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

But I need a css-class for the input field:

```
<fieldset class="group">
    <ul id="checkboxID2" class="choose">
        <li>
            <input id="checkboxID_0" type="checkbox" name="checkboxID$0" value="checkbox_10" class="replace" />
            <label for="checkboxID_0">Checkbox 1</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

I found these two questions:
[Is there a possibility to assign CssClass to CheckBox within CheckBoxList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195987/is-there-a-possibility-to-assign-cssclass-to-checkbox-within-checkboxlist)
[Applying Styles To ListItems in CheckBoxList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104458/applying-styles-to-listitems-in-checkboxlist)

But my question is:
**Is there a way to add a css class without the programmatically way?**
 
I tried `<asp:ListItem class="replace">`, but this generates a `<span class="replace">` around the input field and doesn't work. Additionally I can't change the css classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the suggestion of [TechGirl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3365113/techgirl) I've come up with this:

```
<script>
    $("input[type='checkbox']").addClass("replace");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by 2 ways:
JQuery >

```
$("#selectboxid option:eq(0)").css("color","red");// you can set any color
```

Or Javascript >

```
checkbox {
    color:red
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to set a whole css class instead of one attribute (color) this way?

Comment: yes, $("#selectboxid option:eq(0)").css("class","classname");

Comment: I cannot accept this as answer because it was not completely right. But you get an upvote for helping!

Comment: yes @Thomas, I realised it now, since I think I misread your question, instead of checkbox I assumed its dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

Add this in to the

```
<style>
input[type=checkbox] {
            width: 100px;
        }
</style>
```

Hope it will work