# How to apply CSS to the internal elements of an ASP.NET CheckBoxList control

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, label, webforms, checkboxlist

I need to manipulate the attributes of a `label` element inside an ASP.NET CheckBoxList control.  Each checkbox label needs to have a different class.  The best alternative I see is to apply the classes with jQuery after the fact.  Does anyone know a better method?

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104458/applying-styles-to-listitems-in-checkboxlist) marginally helpful, however, adding an attribute to the list item only wraps the `input` element and the `label` element in a `span` tag with the denoted attributes.

Comment: I think this needs a bit more information. Why does each checkbox need a different control? Are they a defined list of checkboxes that will never change? If not, what rules determine which checkbox gets which class? If so, why are you using the checkboxlist control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you already thought about it, but you can try to make use of ASP.NET Control Adapters. Control adapters let you change the HTML markup produced by ASP.NET controls.

Checkout the links below for a introduction:

- [ASP.NET Quicky: Control adapters](http://blogs.infosupport.com/asp-net-quicky-control-adapters/)
- [Simple Introduction to ASP.NET Control Adapters](http://jesschadwick.blogspot.com/2009/05/leverage-aspnet-control-adapters-for.html)
- [ASP.NET 2.0 CSS Friendly Control Adapters: The White Paper](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/WhitePaper.aspx)
- [MSDN Magazin Article on Control Adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

Variation of Billy's second answer, but without server side code:

Assign the class to checkboxlist itself

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" id="MyCBL" CssClass="MyClass"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Any CSS you apply to the parent element (in this case the checkboxlist, which renders as a table) can be passed to its child elements:

```
<style>
    .MyClass label {color: Blue}
    .MyClass input[type='checkbox'] {background-color: Red}
</style>
```

Comment: Good approach if you write the CSS code yourself. Problem here is that you might want to specify for example Twitter Bootstrap classes, which cannot be done this way.

Answer (score 0):

This might be kind of a hack as I'm not skilled w/ CSS but it worked for me.

Do a for each on each of the list items in the check box list, add an ID attribute to each one. This will assign an ID to each span that is wrapping the label tag. You will want to assign a different id to each list item since you said each one needs a different class.

```
For Each li As ListItem In Me.CheckBoxList1.Items
    li.Attributes.Add("id", "mySpanID")
Next
```

Now you'll need to add a CSS style for this id so it applies to the label tag.

```
<style>
    #mySpanID label { color: Blue }
</style>
```

Another way would be to do the same thing as above but assign a class to each list item and have the class only apply to the label tag.

Assign the class to each list item

```
For Each li As ListItem In Me.CheckBoxList1.Items
    li.Attributes.Add("class", "MyClass")
Next
```

And then add your CSS

```
<style>
    .MyClass label {color: Blue}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I see several different ways of doing this. The first is through css classes.

Server Code:

```
List<ListItem> items = new List<ListItem>();
ListItem item1 = new ListItem("test", "test");
item1.Attributes.Add("class", "specificClass1");
items.Add(item1);
//repeat the last three lines as needed
checkBoxList.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

This will result in, like you said, a span containing the label and input elements. So, you're css would be:

```
.specificClass1 label
{
    //Your specific css
}
```

and you would repeat this as needed.

Another approach would be the jQuery approach. I don't see anything wrong with this approach, but in you're question, you mention this approach negatively. So I'll assume you know how to do it but just don't want to. I just mention it to say it's not a bad approach, and if all else fails, you might want to reconsider :).

Comment: Will this persist after a post back or a partial post back?