# CheckBoxList children CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

Currently, I have this:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkSections" runat="server" onselectedindexchanged="chkSections_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

...which generates this:

```
<table border="0" id="ctl00_cpBody_chkSections">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cpBody$chkSections$0" id="ctl00_cpBody_chkSections_0"><label for="ctl00_cpBody_chkSections_0">All Sections</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cpBody$chkSections$1" id="ctl00_cpBody_chkSections_1"><label for="ctl00_cpBody_chkSections_1">Personal Health Status and Health History</label></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cpBody$chkSections$2" id="ctl00_cpBody_chkSections_2"><label for="ctl00_cpBody_chkSections_2">Physical Activity and Fitness</label></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

**Problem:** I would like all the `input` fields generated to have one specific class. Do not want to use jQuery.

Comment: Added *ASP.NET* tag (since you are not using "Classic ASP"). Also removed *jQuery* tag since you don't want to use that framework. Added *css*.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 FWIW, jquery is a framework for the javascript language

Comment: @BrianWebster - technically yes, but it certainly *looks* unique. :) Update my comment.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Indeed, good edits. Just wanted to point that out in case you weren't very familiar with the framework

Answer (score 1):

Why not set the CssClass on the `<asp:CheckList>` the, in your CSS, use element selectors?

```
<asp:CheckList CssClass="ChLst">
```

```
.ChLst INPUT
{
    background-color: red;
}

<!-- OR: -->

.ChLst TD
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

**EDIT:**
Ah, I understand now. See this question: [Applying Styles To ListItems in CheckBoxList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104458/applying-styles-to-listitems-in-checkboxlist)

Rather than adding the Style attribute, you can add a class attribute.

```csharp
li.Attributes.Add("class", "chListItem");
```

**EDIT 2:**
On second thought, you may be better off with a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) control and jimmying up your own custom solution. Relying on the CheckBoxList and then trying to consume it in jQuery is obviously not working for you.

Comment: I am using the jquery validate plugin and it uses input names as selectors for validation. Since the list is generated, the `name` of each is incremented by 1; thus, am unable to select the elements and make them required for the validation plugin.

Comment: So, since I can't use the `name` attribute for each input, I figured the best way would be to add the class `"required"` for all the checkboxes.

Comment: I suppose so. I've never used the jQuery validate plugin. You may want to add that specification to your question so people will have a better sense of what you are trying to accomplish. Unfortunately, I believe that attribute will be added to the `TD`, not the `INPUT`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried adding that, but it results in a `<span />` being added around the `input` and `label`. I can't seem to find a way to target the actual `input` field.

Comment: @zeddotes - Personally, I avoid ASP.NET controls whenever possible. I find that they cost me more time in workarounds on any non-trivial website. I can accomplish just about everything I need to (with much more succinct HTML) using inline code (foreach instead of Repeater, etc.)

Comment: I hear you. I'm a front-end web dev and i do not prefer working with asp.net at all. thanks for all your help, in any case :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use attribute of ListItem to set class name at server side:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem item in chkSections.Items)
        item.Attributes["class"] = "class_item";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have just tried doing that but the class is not being added to `input` and/or `label` but it is being added to a `span` which wraps the `input` and `label.