# Why do Font-Size and CssClass properties are not working in CheckBoxList in aspx page?

Tags: css, asp.net, fonts, font-size, checkboxlist

I want to increase the font size of `checkboxlist` values so I added `Font-Size = "large"` property inside `<asp:CheckBoxList>` but it's not working.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>  
            <tr>
               <td  style="padding-left:50px;padding-top:20px">
        <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="ChkList" RepeatColumns="4" repeatLayout="Table" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Font-Size="Large"></asp:CheckBoxList>
                   </td>
                </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:50px; padding-top:10px;">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" Font-Size="Small" Text="Submit"></asp:Button>
                </td>
            </tr>


</table>
    </form>
```

I even tried CssClass property as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/104502/2500920) answer but it also not working

CSS:

```
<style>
        .chkboxlist td
    {
    font-size:large;
    }
    </style>
```

ASPX:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table>  
            <tr>
               <td style="padding-left:50px;padding-top:20px;">
        <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="ChkList" RepeatColumns="4" repeatLayout="Table" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="chkboxlist"></asp:CheckBoxList>
                   </td>
                </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:50px; padding-top:10px;">
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Submit" OnClick="Submit_Click" Font-Size="Small" Text="Submit"></asp:Button>
                </td>
            </tr>


</table>
    </form>
```

Also I tried adjusting font-size inside `<td>` but it also not working.

Visual Look of my output:

[image]

Source Code:

```
<table>  
            <tr>
               <td style="padding-left:50px;padding-top:20px;">
                   <table id="ChkList" class="chkboxlist" border="0" style="color:Black;background-color:Transparent;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;">
    <tr>
        <td><span style="color:Black;background-color:Transparent;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;"><input id="ChkList_0" type="checkbox" name="ChkList$0" /><label for="ChkList_0">Agent Checque</label></span></td><td><span style="color:Black;background-color:Transparent;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;"><input id="ChkList_1" type="checkbox" name="ChkList$1" /><label for="ChkList_1">CC Cheque</label></span></td><td><span style="color:Black;background-color:Transparent;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;"><input id="ChkList_2" type="checkbox" name="ChkList$2" /><label for="ChkList_2">Customer Cheque</label></span></td><td><span style="color:Black;background-color:Transparent;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;"><input id="ChkList_3" type="checkbox" name="ChkList$3" /><label for="ChkList_3">DD Cheque</label></span></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><span style="color:Black;background-color:Transparent;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;"><input id="ChkList_4" type="checkbox" name="ChkList$4" /><label for="ChkList_4">Sathiya Cheque</label></span></td><td><span style="color:Black;background-color:Transparent;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;"><input id="ChkList_5" type="checkbox" name="ChkList$5" /><label for="ChkList_5">SathiyaTest</label></span></td><td><span style="color:Black;background-color:Transparent;font-family:Verdana;font-size:8pt;"><input id="ChkList_6" type="checkbox" name="ChkList$6" /><label for="ChkList_6">Test</label></span></td><td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Why these changes are not reflecting the font-size?

Comment: When the page renders, what is the HTML that CheckBoxList becomes?

Comment: ? I can see it in the aspx he posted

Comment: I meant the HTML it generates (right click -> View Source). I believe asp:CheckBoxList generates a table. If we see that then we can see if your <td> have the css class applied to them.

Comment: Yes! I saw the Source Code and found that font-size=8pt; by default. I hope this could be problem. Am I right? added source code in my question.

Comment: Try my code below and check the source code of the rendered page again. Because it is 8px I think the style you tried is not being applied, or is overridden.
If you press F12 and can use the dev tools to change the size in the browser and make sure you _can_ adjust the font size.

Comment: Your <span> inside the <td> has an inline style, and that is causing the smaller font size. We need to track where this is coming from.

Comment: Yes you are correct, `<span>` is having inline which has `font-size:8pt;` but not able to trace where it's coming from :(

Comment: RepeatLayout 'table' does not render span tags ('flow' does that). So it must be coming from elsewhere. That is your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the place where it causing the problem. In my project solution I have *App_themes* folder where one skin file is available. In that skin file we have mentioned all the controls like `font-size`, `backround-color`, `font-style` etc for all `CheckBox`, `CheckBoxList`, `DropDownLists`, `DropDowns`, `Buttons`, `TextBoxs` and `Labels`.

In that file for `CheckBox` font-size is mentioned as `Font-Size="8pt"` so it's reflecting in the output even after I mentioned the Font-Size in the inline property of CheckboxList in my aspx page. Now I changed as `<asp:CheckBox runat="server"  Font-Size="11pt" Font-Names="Verdana" BackColor="transparent" ForeColor="Black"/>` in *.Skin* file which changes the font-size of my checkboxs.

Update:

I created a new skin file named *Checkbox* and mentioned `SkinID="chkFont"` in the below control.

`<asp:CheckBoxList SkinID="chkFont" runat="server"  Font-Size="11pt" Font-Names="Verdana" BackColor="transparent" ForeColor="Black"/>` this in the file.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Theme="Checkbox" CodeFile="FlexExplicitTransactions.aspx.cs" Inherits="HDFC.CTIClient.FlexExplicitTransactions" %>
```

I mentioned theme name as checkbox in my aspx page. In my `CheckboxList` menu I used `SkinID` property as `SkinID="chkFont"` and Run the program. Now the font size of my `CheckboxList` alone increased and not all the other checkboxlist font sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Set the style in the page so we know there is nothing overriding it (you can move this to a css file later). Create a class with a style (again you can refine it later - we're just ensuring we don't make any mistakes in our CSS that cause the element not to get the style).

```
<style>
.chkboxlist
{
font-size:24px;
}
</style>
```

With CssClass applied to the checkboxlist:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="ChkList" RepeatColumns="4" repeatLayout="Table" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="chkboxlist"></asp:CheckBoxList>
```

This should show the larger font size for the label.

Comment: I have already used this style in my code and posted it in my question, right?

Comment: You are using .chkboxlist td, while this is for any item with class chkboxlist (not just td's). It is possible the class is not being applied, because of the td.

Comment: I tried to up-vote your answer but I have only 13 reputation so I am not allowed to up-vote, need 2 more reputation to do that ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found the exact issue and posted an answer. As I said I up-voted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you notice at the runtime the check box list will be converted to tr's and td's.
You can use CSS for this. For example your checkbox id is ChkList. Set ClientIDMode to Static and Then you can define following css property.

```
<style>
#ChkList label
{
font-size:22px;
color:Blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I'm using the ChkList id in checkboxlist for creating Dynamic checkboxes based on one SQL table value. Will setting ClientIDMode to Static affect my dynamic checkbox logic?

Comment: There Should be no issues i guess....For Clear Understanding Refer the following Doc.Its really good. http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40