# How to apply styling to title attribute of dropdown list item?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, webforms

I've created one dropdown in webform project. In this dropdown, I'm showing tooltip to listitems which is different than the displayfield and value field(third column we can say). To bind tooltip to list item with the use of DataTable I have added following code:

```
  private void AddToolTipToDDL(DataTable dt, DropDownList ddl)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in ddl.Items)
        {
            if (item.Value != "0")
            {
                DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
                dv.RowFilter = "MasterID = " + item.Value;
                string s = Convert.ToString(dv[0].Row.ItemArray[4]);
                item.Attributes.Add("Title", s);
            }
        }
    }
```

It will add title attribute to ListItem. 
Now I want to apply styling to the title attribute tooltip. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You haven't even tried anything... Please do some research before asking such simple question. I just googled "style listitem asp.net", took less than a minute, and the first 10 hits are helpfull...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying Styles To ListItems in CheckBoxList](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104458/applying-styles-to-listitems-in-checkboxlist)

Comment: Well you could google that then. Just found a solution to that in less than a minute too http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is found here:
https://weblogs.asp.net/abdullaabdelhaq/adding-tooltip-for-each-list-item

Basically, you add a fixed width to the dropdown list and add the following code:

```
ddl.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", _"this.title=this.options[this.selectedIndex].title");
```

and it works like a charm, if I understand correctly what your were searching for.