# How to display Font Awesome icons in select options using tag helper or html helper?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core-mvc

I have followed the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36743041/font-awesome-icon-in-select-option), but I just get the character codes, e.g. `&#xf007;` in plain text in my `<option>`s.

In my controller, I populate the items for the `SelectList`:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    ViewData["Icons"] = IconsDropdown();
    return View();
}

private SelectList IconsDropdown()
{
    List<ListItem> list = new List<ListItem>()
    {
        new ListItem{ Text = "&#xf007;", Value = "fa-user" },
        new ListItem{ Text = "&#xf508;", Value = "fa-user-tie" },
        // and so on...
    };
    return new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text");
}

class ListItem
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And then I assign the list items to the `select` in the view:

```
<select asp-for="Icon" class="form-control select-fontawesome" asp-items="ViewBag.Icons">
    <option selected disabled value="">Choose icon</option>
</select>
```

I tried removing the class `form-control` too, but it's the same result.

The CSS to set the font:

```
.select-fontawesome {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome', 'sans-serif';
}
```

If I try to display FontAwesome icons in normal text, it works:

```
<span class="fas fa-user"></span>
```

**Update**

Thanks to @MBaas for pointing out that I need the `fa`-class on the `<select>` and `style="font-weight:900;"` on the `<option>`s.

But using the tag-helper, there is no way of setting style on the `<option>`s, so the solution isn't working.

I have been looking for a way of using `@Html.DropDownListFor()` instead of the tag-helper, but so far I haven't found that it will let me add css styling to the `<option>`s. I can set a class on the `<select>`-tag, but that's all:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => 
    m.Icon, 
    ViewBag.Icons, 
    "Choose icon", 
    new { @class= "form-control fa" })
```

Comment: What CSS styles are you are trying to set? ... Be aware that form elements are pretty much impossible to style using CSS, and `option` may be the worst, as almost nothing can be done with it, and using e.g. tag helpers won't overcome that.

Comment: @Ason I'm trying to set `font-weight:900`.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104458/applying-styles-to-listitems-in-checkboxlist

Comment: @Ason No, that is `CheckBoxList`. That is not a dropdown (`<select>`).

Comment: @Ason None of the two other questions cover what I'm asking for. Please reopen my question.

Comment: 1: Yes, the first dupe question talks about a `CheckBoxList` but the answer applies to a dropdown as well. -- 2: It is not because of the other two _questions_ it were closed as a dupe, it is because their answers solve your problem, which you clearly stated were "I'm trying to set `font-weight:900`", and that is done with the `Attributes.Add` method, which again works for several kinds of `ListItem`s.

Comment: @Ason `ListItem` is my own class, and it does not have an `Attributes.Add` method.

Comment: Voted to reopen your question, though since you removed the `css` tag it now takes 2 more votes (or someone with a gold badge in `c#` or `asp.net-core-mvc`)

Comment: And have a look at this post, pretty sure you find you answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc?rq=1 ... and if, I'll change the dupe link to it (if you add the `css` tag back)

Comment: Noticed you added back the `css` tag, so I added the link from my previous comment as the first duplicate link (and kept the other for old .NET Framework users)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen examples that seemed to work w/o any additional CSS or classes - but somehow I can produce something along those lines. But the following worked and works for me ;)

Apply class `fa` to the `select` control (that bit comes with FontAwesome) and then some styling for the options to make sure they are styles with `font-weight: 900`.  `fa`does that as well, but it seems to be overridden by the browser's settings. Our settings then overrides the browser.

```html
   <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
select.fa option {font-weight: 900}
</style>
<select name="sample" id="sample" class="fa">
        <option value="">Choose icon</option>
        <option value="fa-user">&#xf007;</option>
        <option value="fa-user-tie">&#xf508;</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the `fa` class on the `<select>`! But I am unable to set css styling on the `<option>`s using the tag helper or html-helper, so it isn't working anyway.

Comment: I have updated the answer and added a style which takes care of those options. So even the unstyled options display correctly now!

Comment: I guess that would solve it if it weren't for the fact that the Asp html-renderer translates `&` to `&amp;`. I just realised that now. The options look like this: `<option value="fa-user-shield">&amp;#xf505;</option>`.

Comment: Updated the answer again to describe the approach a bit better. Stupid that the renderer decides to overwrite. Anc chance to run some JS to inject the desired content? (Duh, lots of crutches...)

Comment: @Stian and MBaas -- The OP ask how to set styles using _tag helper_ or _html helper_, and no where does your answer show how to do that. They also explicit in their "question edit" states: _But using the tag-helper, there is no way of setting style on the `<option>`s, so the **solution** isn't working._, and in this case they mean your **solution**. The duplicate's answers though, solves what is asked for.